# Standalones input module horizontal axes unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

Hello i was wondering how to access Standalone input modules horizontal axes so that i could change axes input on run time.

Tried google and unity docs, but there wasn't any info how to access horizontal axes value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify input on runtime, but you can use custom variables to store the values and manipulate them programatically before you actually use the value